# The best way to do multiple save() in one submit in Django

Tags: django, save, multiple-tables

I am a newbie in Django, and actually web developing. Have been searching for a while, but haven't got the answer yet.

In my project, when user submits a form request, it will search some websites and if the specific images are found, it will download the images and return the link for download.

Currently I have two Models:

1. Request

   ```
   class Request(models.Model):
       create_time = models.DateTimeField('create time', auto_now_add=True)
       user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET('unknown'))
       image_name = models.CharField(max_length=48)
       image = models.ForeignKey(Image, on_delete=models.SET('unknown'))
   ```
2. Image

   ```
   class Image(models.Model):
       add_time = models.DateTimeField('add time', auto_now_add=True)
       image_source = models.CharField(max_length=48)
       image_size = models.CharField(max_length=48)
   ```

Just wanted to know what is the best way to save() to the models when a request is submitted. The approaches I am thinking of are:

Option A:

1. When a request is received, save() to Request model with basic
   information - except "Image ID" (it is not available yet), and set
   status to "started"
2. Do the searches, and download the images, and then save() to the
   Image model - now I have the "Image ID"
3. Update the Request instance with the "Image ID" information, and
   update the status to "success"

Option B:

1. Search and download the images immediately when the request is
   received, and save() to the Image model - now I have the "Image ID"
2. Save() to the Request model with the "Image ID" - this is a new
   insert activity.

Which is the best way to do it? Or are there any other better ways to do it?

Also, any suggestions to use "transaction" feature of Django for such scenario? I don't prefer it for my small project - just don't want to make it too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the option A and I **strongly suggest you rename** the "Request" model in something different, for example: "SearchRequest" the `Request` is something very specific in the django world and if you add a new context to it you'll be very confused soon.

When the `SearchRequest` is triggered you can save the creation time, the status in `STARTED` and then perform the research. Something can go wrong during the research so it's better if you wrap the search of the images on a try/except. You can then save the status with `FAILED` and the reason if something goes wrong. This answer the question about the atomic transaction, **you don't need that**.

Another suggestion, move the name of the image on the Image model, the SearchRequest can get the images name from the related images.

An improvement on the SearchRequest would be to save the Status as related model so you can reconstruct the change of the status during the search.

```
class SearchRequestStatus(models.Model):
    create_time = models.DateTimeField('create time', auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    search = models.ForeignKey(SearchRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='statuses')
```

This solution can be accomplished in 2 ways:

1. You save the explicitly change of status in the related field
   creating manually a new SearchRequestStatus or..
2. You save the `status` and `status_detail` in the `SearchRequest` and
   a save signal will grab the changes and automatically create a
   `SearchRequestStatus` using a receiver. (see:
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/)

   @receiver(signals.post_save, sender=SearchRequest, weak=False, dispatch_uid="_update_search_request_status_history")
   def _update_search_request_status_history(sender, instance, **kwargs):
       current_status = SearchRequest.objects.filter(search=instance).first()
       if not current_status or current_status.status != instance.status:
           SearchRequestStatus.objects.create(search=instance,
                                              status=instance.status,                                              status_detail=instance.status_detail)

Of course, you must add the fields to your `SearchRequest` model and also add STATUSES tuple to limit the selection of statuses

```
status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=STATUSES.items(), default=`STARTED`)
status_detail = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
```